# How to insert concatenated column values into a table within a loop

Tags: mysql

I have 5 columns with names  - value1, value2 ... value5

I have a while loop that iterates 5 times and over each iteration I'm trying to insert a value into each of the columns, i.e., 5 inserts into 5 different rows. Thus, in each insert I insert into only 1 column and others default to NULL.

I've done something like this, that isn't working. I get the error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'insert_value' in 'field list'

```
set loop_counter = 1;
set loop_limit = 5;

while loop_counter < loop_limit do
     set insert_value = concat('value', loop_counter);    
     insert into values_table (insert_value) values (insert_value);
end while;
```

All this code is within a function that is passed 5 parameters - value1..value5.

Thus, in the insert statement, I'm trying to generate the column name and also need to specify the value that needs to be inserted.

I realize that the insert is wrong, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: "Isn't working" means what? When you run this what happens?

Comment: I get the error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'insert_value' in 'field list'

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be `set @insert_value` and `VALUES (@insert_value)`?

Comment: Yes, that gives a syntax error - 'Missing select'

Comment: Not sure about that, but I can see you never actually increment `loop_counter` here so that's likely a problem.

Comment: I've fixed that. The insert still doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind your code not working is that you can't just populate column_name like that using `concat()`. In order to achieve your task, you need `Prepared Statements`.

Following query will do the job:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ins()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 1;        
    WHILE i <= 5 DO
    set @q := (select concat("Insert into t(",concat('value', i),") values('",concat('value', i),"')"));
        prepare s1 from @q;
        execute s1;
        deallocate prepare s1;                     
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;

CALL ins();

SELECT *FROM t;
```

RESULTS:

```
   value1   value2  value3  value4  value5
------------------------------------------------
    value1  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
    NULL    value2  NULL    NULL    NULL
    NULL    NULL    value3  NULL    NULL
    NULL    NULL    NULL    value4  NULL
    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    value5
```

[Click here for WORKING DEMO](http://rextester.com/CZH4916)

Hope it helps!